# Why is a closed ball in Q closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Why is a closed ball in the metric space of rationals with Euclidean distance closed?

Let $B_\epsilon [q]$ be a closed ball in $Q$. Then any irrational less than $\epsilon$ distance away from q is a limit point of this set but not contained in this set. Hence this closed ball should not be closed as it does not contain its limit point.

Comment: Irrational numbers aren’t in the space $\Bbb Q$ at all, so they are completely irrelevant.

Comment: You mix "complete" and "closed". No balls in $\Bbb Q$ are complete, but closed balls are closed.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Not completely. They are the reason some Cauchy sequences do not converge.

Comment: @Conifold: In a sense; one could also argue that the failure of some Cauchy sequences to converge in $\Bbb Q$ is the reason for the irrational. In any case they are completely irrelevant to **emmy**’s specific concern. I debated forestalling that potential objection and decided that it was preferable not to complicate matters unnecessarily in a mere comment.

Answer (score 0):

In *any* metric space $(X,d)$ the closed ball $B_\varepsilon[x] = \{y \in X\mid d(x,y) \le \varepsilon\}$ is a closed set in $X$. This is a simple consequence of the triangle inequality to show that if $y \notin B_\varepsilon[x]$, then $B_r(x)$ (the open ball around $x$ with radius $r:= d(x,y) - \varepsilon>0$) is disjoint from $B_\varepsilon[x]$, etc.

The irrationals are irrelevant in the case of $X=\Bbb Q$ as the metric space is just an intrinsic thing. We only consider points of $\Bbb Q$ to check if a set is closed.